# React: Auto update date and view with new information called from json API

Tags: json, reactjs, fetch

I am calling data from coinmarketcap.com API and can not find a way to make the code auto update.  I would like to get this code to update the information every 30 seconds or so.

If I call something the wrong thing... or this is a basic question, sorry this is my first week with React.

Here is what I have and it works great at loading the information from coinmarketcap.com on the when the app first loads.

**Main Component (file: Crypto.jsx)**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import CryptoItem from './parts/CryptoItem';

class Crypto extends Component{
render(){

return(
    <div id="CryptoItems">
        <div id="data">
            <CryptoItem cryptocoin="bitcoin" />
            <CryptoItem cryptocoin="ethereum" />
            <CryptoItem cryptocoin="ripple" />
            <CryptoItem cryptocoin="iconomi" />
            <CryptoItem cryptocoin="litecoin" />
            <CryptoItem cryptocoin="bitcoin-cash" />
        </div>
    </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Crypto;
```

**Child Component (file: /parts/CryptoItem.jsx)**

```
        import React, { Component } from 'react';

    const urlForUsername = cryptocoin => `https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/${cryptocoin}/`

    class CryptoItem extends Component {

        constructor(props){
            super(props)
            this.state = {
                requestFailed: false
            }
        }

        componentDidMount(){
            fetch(urlForUsername(this.props.cryptocoin))
            .then(response =>{
                if(!response.ok){
                    throw Error("Network request failed")
                }
                return response
            })
            .then(d => d.json())
            .then(d => {
                this.setState({
                    cryptoData: d[0]
                })
            },() => {
                this.setState({
                    requestFailed: true
                })
            })
        }


        render() {
            if(this.state.requestFailed) return <p>Failed...</p>
            if(!this.state.cryptoData) return <p>Loading...</p>

            return(    
                <ul className="CryptoItem" data-sort={ `${this.state.cryptoData.percent_change_24h}` } id={ `${this.state.cryptoData.symbol}PriceChangeID` }>
                    <li>
                        {this.state.cryptoData.name}:
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        $ <span id={ `${this.state.cryptoData.symbol}Price` }>{this.state.cryptoData.price_usd}</span>
                    </li>
                    <li className="PreCentChange">
                        <span id={ `${this.state.cryptoData.symbol}PriceChange` }>{this.state.cryptoData.percent_change_24h}</span><b>%</b>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            );
        }
    }
    export default CryptoItem;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, extract out the logic in **componentDidMount** method in child component to a separate method as below.

```js
fetchResult = () => {
    fetch(urlForUsername(this.props.cryptocoin))
    .then(response =>{
        if(!response.ok){
            throw Error("Network request failed")
        }
        return response
    })
    .then(d => d.json())
    .then(d => {
        this.setState({
            cryptoData: d[0]
        })
    },() => {
        this.setState({
            requestFailed: true
        })
    })
}
```

After that modify the **componentDidMount** method as below.

```js
componentDidMount(){
  this.fetchResult()
  setInterval(this.fetchResult, 30000)
}
```

Note that, setInterval method can be used to execute a logic periodically. The first argument is the function which contains the logic that needs to be executed periodically. Second argument is the time interval in milliseconds.

Comment: When adding 

`componentDidMount(){
  setInterval(this.fetchResult, 30000)
}`

It errors out with this message **NotFoundError: Failed to execute 'removeChild' on 'Node': The node to be removed is not a child of this node.**

However, if I do this it works just great. 

`componentDidMount(){
  this.fetchResult()
  setInterval(this.fetchResult, 30000)
 }`

Comment: Yes. I've updated my answer. You need to invoke this.fetchResult() method manually for the 1st time. Otherwise it will be invoked for the first time after 30 seconds.

Comment: After some testing, this does not seem to work all the way.  I can see it pulling the updated JSON data.  But it is not updating the view. So all my information on the page is staying the same.                                                                               







So where I am calling `{this.state.cryptoData.price_usd}` in *file: /parts/CryptoItem.jsx*.  That information does not change.

Comment: Is it only the this.state.cryptoData.price_usd property which doesn't get updated? There is a starting $ in that line which is invalid. Further, for any reason if the first request didn't completed within 30 seconds, the second request will be initiated. I think the best solution would be to use Flux.

Comment: Sorry about that, it was my error that made it not work. Thank you again for the help.